# Django Twilio - Not all unsubscribers are being captured in my app - why?

Tags: django, twilio, twilio-api

I've implemented a function to capture unsubscribers. However, only some of the unsubscribers are captured by my app. For example I am getting multiple  `21610 - Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient` for customers that have replied stop and were not captured in my app as unsubscribers.

Here is the part of phone number sms webhook that checks if user wants to unsubscribe:

```
        umessage_body = str(request.POST['Body']).upper()
        if umessage_body == 'STOP' or umessage_body == 'STOPALL' or umessage_body == 'UNSUBSCRIBE' or umessage_body == 'CANCEL' or umessage_body == 'END' or umessage_body == 'QUIT':
            place_num = request.POST['To']

            Unsubscriber.objects.update_or_create(
                unsubscriber_number = request.POST['From'],
                place = place
            )

            resp = MessagingResponse()
            return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```

For context my app sends text messages to thousands of users at once, maybe it is something about my webhook being overwhelmed. Any idea what is causing this, and how to ensure all unsubscribers are being captured in my app.

Comment: The keywords may also come in lowercase, is your code case sensitive?

Comment: @Alan my code was already case insensitive, I added the line I use to take care that to my question. So that is not the issue.